# Get path of Windows service EXE (to use as a parameter at installation and runtime)

Tags: windows, delphi, service

Is it possible to get the path of the Windows service EXE

1. at installation time, to modify the service display name, and
2. at runtime, to use as a parameter?

`GetCurrentDir` etc. of course gives `system32` folder.

The problem I would like to solve is that I want multiple instances of it running, with a parameter passed to it which will determine name and behaviour. My proposed solution was to use a folder name, e.g.:

```
C:\MyProgramDirectory\bin\1\MyService.exe
C:\MyProgramDirectory\bin\2\MyService.exe
C:\MyProgramDirectory\bin\3\MyService.exe
```

I want the service to

- pick up this directory name at install, so its service/display name would be "*MyServiceX*":

  ```
  procedure TMyService.ServiceLoadInfo(Sender: TObject);
    begin

      name        := 'MyServiceX'; // Get this by extracting X from EXE directory
      DisplayName := 'MyServiceX'; // Get this by extracting X from EXE directory
    end;

  procedure TMyService.ServiceBeforeInstall(Sender: TService);
    begin
      ServiceLoadInfo(Sender);
      inherited;
    end;

  procedure TMyService.ServiceBeforeUninstall(Sender: TService);
    begin
      ServiceLoadInfo(Sender);
      inherited;
    end;
  ```
- pick up this directory name at runtime to use as a parameter to determine behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service can get its own `.exe` file path by calling `ParamStr(0)`.

However, a cleaner solution that doesn't require having multiple copies of the `.exe` is to pass extra command-line parameters when (un)installing and running the service. The service can look for those parameters to update its `Name`/`DisplayName` as needed. See this question for how to do that:

[Is it possible to install multiple instances of the same delphi service application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612587/)

Comment: Thank you for ParamStr(0), I thought it was just another call to GetCurrentDir. Regarding only one .exe - yes much cleaner, however this would mean that all instances of the service would have to be stopped for an update to the exe? I can imagine scenarios where I might need these services to be running a different version to each other